# Enable browser autocomplete when submitting a form via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

After googling for a while I can't found a good answer for my problem.

I have a form that is displayed using a modal windows (bootbox for instance). This form is submitted using ajax post, but the browser can't store input values (autocomplete) so that it can display these values when showing this form again.

```js
function openModal(view) {
  var buttons = {};

  buttons.success = {
    label: "Salvar",
    className: "btn-primary",
    callback: function() {
      var $form = box.find("form");
      var valuesToSubmit = $form.serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: valuesToSubmit,
        dataType: "json"
      }).success(function(response) {
        box.modal('hide');
        if (successCallback) {
          successCallback();
        }
      }).error(function(response) {
        box.find(".modal-body").html(response.responseText);
        enableBasicControls(box);
        if (errorCallback) {
          errorCallback();
        }
      });

      return false;

    }
  };

  buttons.danger = {
    label: "Cancelar",
    className: "btn-danger"
  };

  box = bootbox.dialog({
    title: title,
    animate: false,
    message: view,
    onEscape: function() {},
    buttons: buttons,
    size: "large"
  });
}
```

```html
<form asp-action="Create">
    <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" />
    <input asp-for="ConsultaId" type="hidden" />

    <div class="row">
        <input data-focus="true" data-select="true" class="form-control" type="number" data-val="true" data-val-required="The QtdEmbalagens field is required." id="QtdEmbalagens" name="QtdEmbalagens" value="1">
        
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input rows="4" class="form-control" type="text" id="Observacao" name="Observacao" value="">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Afaik, the browser's auto-complete for inputs is based on the input's `name` and `type` attributes; yours have neither.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. Aspnet give a name and id for elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem submitting to a fake page using iframe:

```
<iframe name="myframe" id="frame1" src="Create" style="display: none;"></iframe>

<form asp-action="Create" target="myframe">
    <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" />
....


function openModal(view) {
    var buttons = {};
    buttons.success = {
        label: "Salvar",
        className: "btn-primary",
        callback: function () {
            var $form = box.find("form");
            var  url = $form.attr('action');
            $form.attr('action', "about:blank");
            $form.submit();//======================== fake

            var valuesToSubmit = $form.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url, //sumbits it to the given url of the form
                data: valuesToSubmit,
                dataType: "json"
            ...
```